# MVC Pass additional information to the Controller on Create of new page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am currently using the following:

```
<input type="submit" id="SaveNew" value="Create" />
```

which will submit the Create page.
It then calls the Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Prog prog)
```

I have additional information on the screen besides the Model `Prog` that also needs to be send to the Controller. How do I do this? How is it possible to do something like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Prog prog, var1, var2, var3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just name the form elements as the variables in the method signature. Everything should stay in the same form.
Model:

```
public class SimpleModel
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
<%= Html.BeginForm("Process", "Home") %>
<%= Html.TextBox("Number") %> <!-- This is Model property -->
<%= Html.TextBox("additional") %> <!-- This is additional parameter -->
<input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Process(SimpleModel model, string additional)
{
    // ...
    // model.Number will have the value from the "Number" text box
    // additional will have the value from the "additional" text box
}
```

Comment: Bojan, say if I have a text box with id: Customer1. How do I go about passing this to the controller. I tried what you mentioned the way I understood it but didn't quite work.

Comment: Nate, do you have the name attribute on the text box as well?

Comment: I have something like: <input type="text" name="MngFn" id="MngFn"/>. Can you show an example of how this would work. Thanks

Comment: you have to set the same input's `name` property in your action's argument. Something like `public ActionResult Process(SimpleModel model, string MngFn)`.